# STM32 USART Rx Interrupt doesn´t work correctly

Tags: interrupt, stm32, usart, stm32f4

I´m using the STM32F407, and work on a project which I try to receive data with the USART3.

**Project Overview:**

I have to send a special PWM sequenz over a wire. After I sent the PWM, I´ve got on the same wire a response of serial data instantly (USART standard, 8N1). I generate the PWM with the timer1 update interrupt. After the last pulse I deactivate the timer1 interrupt an activate the USART Rx interrupt. Then - normaly - I should receive the serial data. The code which receive data and store them in a ringbuffer works very fine in a other project.

**My problem:**

The serial data, which are incoming will **sometimes** received correctly (It´s a stream of 96 single bytes). With an oscilloscope which can decode the USART signals I can see that the correct data arriving the USART Rx Pin. But the USART Rx interrupt doesn´t work correctly. Mostly I receive only one Byte (only one interrupt). To debug the ISR, I have saved the SR, DR and CR1 register into a array to log which of the error flags occured. The register values shows me, that ervery time, the reception of the frame failed, I have one or more different error flags set. Noise error, overrun error and framing error. But if sometimes the reception works, I see that no error flags was set.

I thought that an Rx interrupt will generate everytime a byte arrived at the USART independent of the state of the error flags...

I have really no idea why the ISR only works one time if there is an error flag.

Could someone help me?

**Update 1**

Here is a short update. 
I talked widh somebody who told me, it could be a problem that the USART receive the PWM signals too. I will try to change the state of the pin as an output while the USART is still running. After the last PWM pulse I will change the state of the Pin as UASRT Rx input. Maybe this could be fix the problem if the USART only can receive serial signals. I will post my proccress here.

**Solution**

Last week I solved my problems.

First I have the problem that a function configure the Rx pin to an input for another peripheral...  (._.)

The second problem was the bad signal quality. The USART of the STM32 have the possibility to work in the ONEBIT mode. This mode (as I understood) sample ervery bit only one time and not three times of each bit. So I increase the tolerance of my USART to 3,88%.

Finally, but this is just to be on the safe side, I cleared all pending USART interrupt bits before I activate the USART Rx interrupt.

Now I can receive the incoming frame reliable.

Thanks for the comments and the help.

Comment: We also have no idea without any code to analyze...

Comment: Sorry for that, but I cant post my code at the moment. The only thing I can say is, that the absolutely same code is running fine in a other project, were I receive serial data too. But I will post the code asap.

Comment: Is your hardware okay? Do you have nice clean 3V3 signals at the IO pin? Is the grounding correct? Is the baud rate correct? On an STM407 USART1 and 6 are on a different clock to the other USARTs (APB2 vs APB1). It is the same with the timers, some are on different buses. If you move code for the USART or Timer from one to the other then the baud rate or timers settings would be wrong. I have fallen foul of this before.

Comment: Thanks for relpy. Ok ich will check the hardware once again. The configuration of the USART seems to be correct, bacause I can receive sometimes the complete frame correcty. And I dont change the basic configuration. The only thing I change is the Interrupt enable ...

Comment: Wich IDE are you using?

Comment: I´m useing the CooCox IDE.